# How to find scalar multiples that would make sum of matrices the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What are all the possible values of $c_1$,$c_2$,$c_3$ $\in$ **R** such that

$c_1$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\ -1&0 \end{bmatrix} $ + $c_2$$\begin{bmatrix} 2&1\\ -2&2\end{bmatrix} $ +$c_3$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\ -1&-2 \end{bmatrix} $ =$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} $

---

I tried to make a coefficient matrix of the values of $c_1$, $c_2$ & $c_3$ with the following equations:

$c_1$+2$c_2$+$c_3$= 0

$c_2$-$c_3$= 0

-$c_1$-2$c_2$-$c_3$= 0

2$c_2$-2$c_3$= 0

but that did not work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$c_2-c_3=0$ and $2c_2-2c_3$, $c_1+2c_2+c_3=0$ and $-c_1-2c_2-c_3=0$ are equivalent, so given linear system is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Using Gaussian elimination, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus $c_1=-3c_3$ and $c_2=c_3$. For example, $c_1=-3$, $c_2=1$, $c_3=1$ satisfies the given equation.

Comment: I realized my mistake, I wasn't reducing properly. Thank you so much for the quick reply.